# Пропадает фон(видео), при рендеринге видео с моделькой

Tags: видео, blender

Пропадает видео фон при рендеринге [image: Как должно быть рендеринга] [image: Как происходит после рендеринга]

Comment: Подскажите как это исправить

Answer (score 0):

Вы разместили изображение как background, это вспомогательный объект, на рендере не отображается. Чтобы добавить изображение в сцену используйте аддон Import images as planes (включите в настройках)